# How can I calculate regression in R on a categorical dependent variable (i.e. "Not much", "A bit", "A lot")?

Tags: r, statistics, regression, linear-regression, categorical-data

To make it easy:

- **Input variables are both numerical and categorical:** sex (M/F), beauty (on a scale from 1 to 10), etc...
- **My output is categorical**: '*How often do you want to do X*'? And it goes from "Not very often" to "Very often".

Is there a way to see if the input variables affect the final answer?

Would converting the categorical dependent variable in numbers from 1 to 4 work or is it a stupid idea?

Comment: I think what you are looking for here is called ordinal least square regression. Check this `?MASS::polr`

Comment: @ekoam i think it should be ordinal regression.. not possible to do least squares on a ordinal response?

Comment: My bad. Should be ordinal __logistic__ regression.

Comment: @ekoam thanks, I tried with polr and after a few tweakings it seems to be working. I just need to figure out the significance but other than that it appears to have worked, thanks!